# while loop with if statement not working

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, break

By way of an example I have a txt file that contains a list of dogs, one on each line of the file and then "**" on the last line.  I then have the following code to load this into an `ArrayList` to use in a `JComboBox`.

This way I can simply add another line in the text box to add another dog.

My example code is as follows

```
public class test{
static String temp;

public static void main(String[] args) {
List<String> picklistDogs = new ArrayList<String>();
File picklistFile = new File (filePath);
try {
    BufferedReader loadPickList = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(picklistFile));
    while(true) {
        temp = loadPickList.readLine();
        if (temp != "**") {
            picklistDogs.add(temp);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    loadPickList.close();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("file not found");
}
catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("file io error");
}
} // END of main
} // END of class test
```

My problem seams to be that the `if` statement never triggers the `break` to exit the `while` loop.

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I added what I think is the language tag. Please amend if this is not correct. (And do tag the language in future.)

Comment: this is not how you compare a `String`

Comment: Thanks guys for all the comments, I found quite a few examples on here that did it the way I did above.  Using the `equals` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `!temp.equals("**")` .Try below code

```
if (!temp.equals("**")) {
                picklistDogs.add(temp);
            } else {
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aniket

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare strings better to use java.lang.String#equals